# getchar() in c while using it

Tags: c, eof, getchar, putchar

```
main ()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
      putchar(c);
    }
}
```

I know that `getchar()` buffers the character. If i execute this program and input some character like `Hello` and without pressing enter I pressed `EOF` character why it printing `Hello` again and asking for new character?

Comment: _I pressed EOF character_ means what you did?

Comment: `EOF`, in windows it is `CTRL+Z`. while in Linux, it will be `CTRL+D`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type the 'EOF' character, the terminal driver makes all the characters in the input buffer available to the program, even if you've not typed a newline.  Since the code underneath `getchar()` got some characters, it wasn't at EOF yet.  When you type the second 'EOF', there are no characters left to be sent (but the terminal driver lets the `read()` function know there were 0 bytes available), so the `read` gets 0 bytes returned, which indicates EOF.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your program doesn't receive input from the shell until you have entered a full line. Till then it is stored in the terminal program's buffers. By default, the terminal will buffer all information until ENTER is pressed, before even sending it to the C program.

Comment: But when I pressed first EOF why it is acting like I pressed Enter key .

Answer (score 1):

Just as `getchar` fills a buffer and then "reads" a character at a time, `putchar` does the same thing when printing characters. To perform character at a time I/O, you need to open the input and output streams in an unbuffered mode. However, that can be very inefficient, particularly if program input and output are being read and written directly to and from files or pipes. Instead, work with buffered input and output when possible or put in explicit calls to `flush` any output streams whenever you really need the output to be written whether the I/O buffer is full or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux and probably gcc then you have to press ctrl+D for EOF. And of course press it twice if you're not pressing enter after entering few characters.

Comment: learning: I had the same question- why do i need to press it twice?

Comment: Pressing enter or first EOF is for providing buffer to C. Think of it like if buffer is not empty then EOF just act as completion signal and inputting in buffer is complete (it is not inserted as a character in buffer). And if buffer is empty than its a character. So only if you input EOF only and no other character, then program exits.